# Postgres. How to Create TEMP TABLE, that is unique for current transaction?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions, temp-tables

I wish to materialize some queries placed in stored function.
I have materialized query in TEMP TABLE. But I have to consider a constraint:
temp table must be **unique** for each stored function's call.
Each temp table instance **should be seen only in current transaction**.
Could it be specified during creation of temp table or it work by default?

My first try was:

```
WITH cte2 AS MATERIALIZED (
      SELECT
        arg_date,
        RANK() over(ORDER BY cte1.arg_date DESC) AS DATE_RANK
      FROM cte1
   )
```

it didn't make function faster, unfortunately...
Next, i have tried to use a TEMP TABLE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_f
###### some code
AS $function$
###### some code
begin
######
###### some code
######
CREATE TEMP TABLE cte2 ON COMMIT DROP as
   with cte1 AS (
        SELECT 
            arg_date::date AS arg_date
        FROM UNNEST(date_array) AS arg_date
   )
    SELECT
        cte1.arg_date,
        date_part('year', cte1.arg_date) AS ARG_YEAR,
        RANK() over(ORDER BY cte1.arg_date DESC) AS DATE_RANK
      FROM cte1
   ;
#######
####### some code
#######
end;
####### some code
$function$
```

TEMP TABLE usage has made function 3 times faster!!!

Is that temp table cte2 **UNIQUE** for each stored function's call?
In documentation was written:

> PostgreSQL instead requires each session to issue its own CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE command.

And "ON COMMIT DROP" will **delete** temp table with transaction's end.
But what about **creation** new unique temp table with each transaction's start?
Each temp table instance **should be seen only in current transaction**.
Can it also be specified or it work by default?

Сan someone explain this, please?

Comment: If you have `ON COMMIT DROP` the transaction end will drop the table so the next transaction will get a new version. The table name won't be unique but the instance will be.

Comment: Will two table instances be unique if two transactions are running at the same time?

Comment: The only way I know to have two transactions run at the same time is in different sessions and in that case each session will have it's own table instance. In the end to prove it to yourself you will need to set up a test case